# Closed set and set, closed in $\mathfrak M$

Tags: metric-spaces

I've read in my textbook that a set $A$ is called *closed* if it contains its limit points, i.e. $A'\subseteq A$. But then, coming to next chapter, I came across a term of set $B$, *closed in metric space $\mathfrak M$* (or in its set? this was not quite clear in the book).

I'm not sure how I should understand it. After some thinking it seems that the first definition of a "just closed" set without any reference to *where* it is closed implied some set which would contain the limit points we're interested in. From this, $B$ is closed in $\mathfrak M$ would mean that

$$( x\in\mathfrak M)\wedge(x\in B')\implies x\in B.$$

Thus, the set $B$ may be closed in $\mathfrak M$, but not closed in $\mathfrak N$, e.g. for the case $B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$, $\mathfrak M=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$, $\mathfrak N=\mathbb Q$, where $\mathfrak M$ and $\mathfrak N$ have the standard metric $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that when we talk about closed sets, we need to specify in what metric space it's closed in. In fact, this generalizes to not just metric spaces, but **topological spaces**.

In general, if $X$ is a topological space and $Y \subseteq X$ is given the **subspace topology**, then we say that a subset $A \subseteq Y$ is **closed in $Y$** iff there is some set $C \subseteq X$ such that $A = C \cap Y$ and $C$ is **closed in $X$**.

For example, consider $X = \mathbb R$ and $Y = (2, 7) \subseteq X$, each with the standard topology (that is, view each of them as a metric space with the standard metric $\rho(x, y) = |x - y|$). Notice that $Y$ is not closed in $X$. Now consider $A = [4, 7)$. Notice that $A$ is not closed in $X$, but we do have that $A$ is closed in $Y$ (since $A = [4, 8] \cap Y$ and $[4, 8] \subseteq X$ is closed in $X$).

Comment: Did you mean $A=[4,7]\cap Y$ instead of $...8]$?

Comment: That would work as well. It doesn't matter which set closed in $X$ that was intersected. We could also use $A = [4, 42] \cap Y$.

Comment: Ah, here $[4,8]$ is that $C$ which you mentioned earlier, I see.